# I installed Linux Mint 13 Maya (MATE) 64 bit, what should I choose when asked between Ubuntu, Fedora, etc?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, distributions

Every other download for Linux, I'm being asked what distribution I have (Ubuntu, Fedora, Debian etc)

What should I choose having installed Linux Mint 13 Maya (MATE) 64 bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint#Linux_Mint_Ubuntu-based_Editions):

> As of version 13, Linux Mint gives users the choice between Cinnamon and MATE, as their default desktop environment in the main release edition, with Ubuntu as its base. The following Ubuntu derived editions are also available:

So packages for Ubuntu 12.04 (according to the [list of Mint releases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_Mint_releases)) should work.